# Does the "~" character have any special meaning in python 3?

Tags: python, special-characters

Someone who I took over their position as data analyst has a program that searches for a "bad character" in a filename which they assigned in a variable to "~".  This prints out "bad character in filename".  It is printing out when checking a folder if a file exists there but I don't understand why.  The program just looks for if the filestamp of the file being added was today, doesn't matter the name.

```
for filename in os.listdir(strSrcName):    # llok through files in the directory of the second row in SQL table, SAT_Report_Status
            mdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(strSrcName + filename).st_ctime).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            jdate =  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(strSrcName + filename).st_ctime).strftime('%Y/%j')
            if filename.find(strFileName) >=0:   # If number of files is 0 or more?
                badchar = "~"   # Not sure what this is for
                if filename[0] in badchar:
                    print("Bad Char found in file name, skipping...")
                else:
                    if mdate == fdate or jdate == juldate:  # if the files timestamp == the current timestamp (now)
                        print(strFileName + " Found! Counting and Moving...")
```

Does this have any special meaning in Python?  I don't even know what it means in general

Comment: *I don't understand why* - I guess you should ask your coworker. For some reason he wants to skip files starting with that character

Comment: This has more to do with the OS itself.  In Windows a file prefixed with `~` signifies a temporary file which your coworker probably wanted to skip over.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I guess I would if he were still here but now I'm in his position

Comment: Well, try to reach him... It's his program and for some reason he chose to do that. It will be only guessing coming from us and not very productive...

Comment: @Tomerikoo suppose the previous script owner, whom OP may have never met, was let go or left on bad terms... how do you suppose OP get an answer from them? This is just not a good suggestion.  Sometimes we are just left with the legacy of our predecessors and try to make the best of it.

Comment: @Krrr well, how do you suppose OP get an answer from **us**? This is also just not a good approach. If we are left with legacy, as you said, we can *try to make the best of it*. This doesn't mean asking people who have no clue of the script, the company and everything around it. We can only guess... A better approach will be to talk with other co-workers or try to make sense of it by context (other parts of the scipt, other scripts, files etc...)

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm just asking if this character has any special purpose itself.  But I realize Its just a string character or like Krr said its more of an operating system issue for temporary files.  now I have a new question why python thinks its temporary.  Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @BenSmith Python doesn't think it's temporary, it doesn't think anything of it at all.  All python sees are a list of file names passed by the OS into the script.  The script is trying to weed out the temporary files that were passed by the OS, which all have the `~` in front of it so they're easily identified.  The file names can literally be anything and Python couldn't care less.

Answer (score 1):

To give a proper answer - `"~"` doesn't really have a special meaning in Python as it's just a piece of `str` object.  The literal character `~` however is [used in binary operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), but is not your concern at the moment.

As mentioned, your script seems to be looking for file names beginning with a `~`.  This has to do with the OS - in Windows, files beginning with `~` denotes a temporary file, which your script seems to want to ignore (probably because the data is not meaningful to the script).

Comment: There is nothing special about the "~" at the beginning of file names in Windows, although Windows may use "~" when it generates an 8.3 version of a long file name (although usually not at the beginning of the 8.3 version).

Comment: You're right that it's not windows, but MS Office apps tend to create a temporary file in the same directory as the document with a "~" at the beginning of the filename.